# How to convert list of nested dictionaries into string and vice versa

Tags: python, mysql, string, list, dictionary

I need to store a list of nested dictionaries in MySQL. The only way I see is to convert it to the string and store it in a `TEXT` field. The challenge is how to convert it back from string?

for example:

```
import json                                                                     

val1 = {"aaa":1}                                                                
val2 = {"bbb":2}                                                                   
val3 = {"ccc":3}                                                                   

values = [                                                                         
          json.dumps(val1),                                                        
          json.dumps(val2),                                                        
          json.dumps(val3),                                                        
]                                                                                  

values_str = str(values)                                                           

values_str                                                                         
#'[\'{"aaa": 1}\', \'{"bbb": 2}\', \'{"ccc": 3}\']'
```

Now I can safely store it in MySQL, but then how to convert it back to it's original shape.

I tried using `.split()` but it is not splitting it correctly. Also I haven't include `,` in a dictionaries, but they will be there, so spiting by `,` is not an option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting json strings in the values list, just json encode the list of dicts.

```
values = [val1, val2, val3]
values_str = json.dumps(values)

# Then read it back
values = json.loads(values_str)
```

If you **really** had to do this, then you could do it like so

```
import ast
values = ast.literal_eval(values_str)
values = [json.loads(item) for item in values]
```

Comment: You are so right! I'm ashamed now, by asking this question =)

Answer (score 2):

Try the pickle module. You can serialize your objects to a string then convert them back to the original object.

```
import pickle

val1 = {"aaa":1}                                                                
val2 = {"bbb":2}                                                                   
val3 = {"ccc":3} 
a = pickle.dumps((val1,val2,val3)) # pickle the objects
# "((dp0\nS'aaa'\np1\nI1\ns(dp2\nS'bbb'\np3\nI2\ns(dp4\nS'ccc'\np5\nI3\nstp6\n."

# store in sql database as string

b = pickle.loads(a) # get original objects
# ({'aaa': 1}, {'bbb': 2}, {'ccc': 3})
```